# When does the set of integer linear combinations of 3 vectors in the plane form a dense subset?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Is there an easy to check if and only if condition for when the set of integer combinations of 3 vectors in the plane will form a dense subset of the plane? It seems like having no vector being a multiple of another, and having all 3 vectors being linearly independent over the field ${\mathbb Q}$, and not having any coordinate where all 3 vectors are rational multiples of one another is a necessary condition, but I'm not sure if it's sufficient.

Comment: Clear how to do it with 4, because you can do it with 2 incommensurable vectors in the line, then two in an independent direction. Not sure about 3.

Comment: Alright, by a single linear transformation, we lose no generality by insisting that one of the vectors be $(1,0)$ and the second one be $(0,1).$ About the third vector: it is known that the winding line on the torus is dense iff the slope is irrational, further we know we need both $(x,y)$ components irrational as well as their ratio. However, although i think this is written down somewhere, not sure about your more demanding condition.

Answer (score 1):

As I said, we can demand the first two vectors to be the standard coordinate vectors, so they give the standard integral lattice. Then, on page 28 of [*Diophantine Approximations* by Ivan Niven](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486462676.html) we find

**Kronecker's Theorem**: Given irrationals $\alpha, \beta$ such that  $1,\alpha, \beta$ are linearly independent over the rationals. Then
 the points $$ ( m \alpha - \lfloor    m \alpha \rfloor \; , \; \;  m
 \beta - \lfloor    m \beta \rfloor )  $$ for $m = 1,2,3,4, \ldots$ are
 dense in the unit square.

Proof takes pages 28-31.
As a result, the integer coefficient sums of the three vectors are dense in the plane.

NEXT DAY: Kronecker's hypothesis is **stronger** than just $\alpha, \beta, \beta/\alpha$ irrational. For example, with $\alpha = \pi, \beta = \pi + 1,$ which does give a dense winding line but fails Kronecker's hypothesis, any $(m \alpha, m \beta) = (m \pi, m \pi + m )$ is equivalent, mod the lattice, to $(m \pi, m \pi  ),$ which is, in turn equivalent to some point $(t,t)$ in the fundamental region $0 \leq x < 1, 0 \leq y < 1.$ Not only are these points not dense in the square, they all lie on a single line segment. For $\alpha = p \pi, \beta = q \pi + r$ with nonzero integers $p,q,r,$ all of Kronecker's points lie on a finite number of parallel line segments, equally spaced.